# What is the git command to diff against a remote which has not been merged yet?

Tags: git, merge, diff

What is the git option to diff against a remote which has not been merged yet? ie if you do a git fetch and want to see what difference will be applied what is the git option for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git diff remotes/origin/master master
```